# Results and queries are not displaying in HTML from a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, wampserver

I am designing a database for a non profit organization in which I am a volunteer. In 2012, I studied the basics in databases, using MySQL, SQL and PHP in WampServer 2.2. I already knew how to program in HTML.

For the project I am undertaking at the non profit organization I am using WampServer 2.5. At the time I was unaware that I would quickly run into problems.

As usual creating the website and the various forms within Apache was easy. Creating the database with SQL scripts, in which I inputted directly into WampServer's User Interface worked without incident; However, transferring the data from the HTML form to the database through PHP has been fraught with difficulty. One of the errors that I was getting was a MySQL extension deprecated in PHP error. I found that most of what I had learned in my studies, have been pretty much useless since the modules within WampServer were upgraded in the latest edition.

While I was attempting to research my problem, I came across this tutorial:
[using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17)

The tutorial comes with sample code in which can be used freely. I have been able to use most of the code with success; however, I am having difficulty displaying my results in HTML. I have read through the tutorial and feel that I am missing something that my mind is just not coming to terms with. I am a beginner / amateur at best.

I will not display the HTML code for my input form, since it's just a form with nothing special in it. It contains no PHP and it posts to outputted.php

Here is my code:

### db_functions.php

```
    <?php
/**
* Database functions for a MySQL with PHP tutorial
* 
* @copyright Eran Galperin
* @license MIT License
* @see http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17
*/

/**
* Connect to the database
* 
* @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
*/
function db_connect() {

// Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
static $connection;
// Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
if(!isset($connection)) {
    // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
    // Put the configuration file outside of the document root
    $config = parse_ini_file('../../config.ini'); 
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
}
// If connection was not successful, handle the error
if($connection === false) {
    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
    return mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
return $connection;
}
/**
* Query the database
*
* @param $query The query string
* @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
*/
function db_query($query) {
// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
// Query the database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
return $result;
}
/**
* Fetch rows from the database (SELECT query)
*
* @param $query The query string
* @return bool False on failure / array Database rows on success
*/
function db_select($query) {
$rows = array();
$result = db_query($query);
// If query failed, return `false`
if($result === false) {
    return false;
}
// If query was successful, retrieve all the rows into an array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
}
/**
* Fetch the last error from the database
* 
* @return string Database error message
*/
function db_error() {
$connection = db_connect();
return mysqli_error($connection);
}
/**
* Quote and escape value for use in a database query
*
* @param string $value The value to be quoted and escaped
* @return string The quoted and escaped string
*/
function db_quote($value) {
$connection = db_connect();
return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
}
?>
```

### outputed.php

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>104.9 LIMEFM MEMBERSHIP DATABASE</TITLE>
<STYLE>
TEXT-DECORATION=NONE
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<STYLE>
A {TEXT-DECORATION: NONE}
</STYLE>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#D9FFD9" TEXT="Black" LINK="Black" ALINK="Black" VLINK="Black">

<CENTER>

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0">

<TR><TD COLSPAN="3">&nbsp;</TR>

<TR>
<TD WIDTH="340" ALIGN="left"><A HREF="help/help_index.html" TARGET="_blank"><IMG SRC="./images/help_button.png" WIDTH="62" HEIGHT="62" ALT="Help"></A>
<TD WIDTH="350" ALIGN="center"><IMG SRC="./images/limefm(green).jpg" WIDTH="143" HEIGHT="62" ALT="104.9 LimeFM">
<TD WIDTH="350" ALIGN="right"><B>Powered by: wAmp 2.5</B></P>Brought to you by:<BR><IMG SRC="./images/hills_designing_logo(green).jpg" ALT="Hill's Designing">
</TR>

</TABLE>

</P><HR WIDTH="1000"></P>

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10">

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center" BGCOLOR="#338928"><B><FONT COLOR="white" SIZE="5">outputted.php</FONT></B></TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center"><HR WIDTH="1000"></B></TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TR>

</TABLE>

</CENTER>

<?php   

/**
* Inserting data from input_record.html into the following tables in database limefm_members:
* 
* members,
* ship_info,
* comments.
*/

// This is working, although I am not getting any notification that it is working.

//First I call for the functions
require("db_functions.php");

$member_Id=$_POST['member_Id'];
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
$Po_Box=$_POST['Po_Box'];
$Street=$_POST['Street'];
$City=$_POST['City'];
$State=$_POST['State'];
$Country=$_POST['Country'];
$Del=$_POST['Del'];
$WFTD=$_POST['WFTD'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$DateJoined=$_POST['DateJoined'];
$Type=$_POST['Type'];
$RenewalDate=$_POST['RenewalDate'];
$LastContacted=$_POST['LastContacted'];
$MYOB_ID=$_POST['MYOB_ID'];
$Comment=$_POST['Comment'];

// I chose not to use syntax like: $email=db_quote($_POST['email']);

// Insert the values into the database

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`member_id`,`title`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`po_box`,`street`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`del`,`phone`,`mobile`,`email`,`wftd`) VALUES ('','$Title','$LastName','$FirstName','$Po_Box','$Street','$City','$State','$Country','$Del','$phone','$mobile','$email','$WFTD')");

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `ship_info` (`member_id`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`date_joined`,`type`,`renewal_date`,`last_contacted`,`myob_id`) VALUES ('','$LastName','$FirstName','$DateJoined','$Type','$RenewalDate','$LastContacted','$MYOB_ID')");

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`member_id`,`lastName`,`firstName`,`comment`) VALUES ('','$LastName','$FirstName','$Comment')");

echo"Attempting to display your last entered entry:</P>";


echo"Table 1: Members:</P>";

// result not displaying

$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM members WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");
if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}

echo"Table 2: Ship_info:</P>";

// result not displaying
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM ship_info WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");
if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}

echo"Table 2: Comments:</P>";

// result not displaying
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");
if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}

?>

<CENTER>

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10">

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD><HR WIDTH="1000"></TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD ALIGN="center"><FONT SIZE="5" COLOR="red">The Success or Failure for Records being added are not being displayed.</FONT><BR>
                       <FONT SIZE="5" COLOR="black">The only current way for verifying data is through: </FONT><A HREF="../phpmyadmin/">
                       <FONT SIZE="5" COLOR="black"><B>phpMyAdmin.</B></FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="./images/limefm_icon.jpg"><A HREF="input_record.html"><FONT SIZE="5">Input Next Record?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="./images/limefm_icon.jpg"><A HREF="../phpmyadmin/"><FONT SIZE="5">Check Results?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="./images/limefm_icon.jpg"><A HREF="index.html"><FONT SIZE="5">Return Home?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

</TABLE>

</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

As you can see from the above code, once the values from the variables were placed into the database (which is occurring), I wanted to display the last entered record on the screen to verify the entry's success, so that the PHP Admin wasn't needed. It is my desire that people who are not as computer literate will be able to access the database by the input forms I am creating. If I can't display the results from outputted.php, then I won't be able to draw up forms necessary to search the database based on commonly used queries.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing you learned back in those courses is useless. Just because you now learn to use another database connector does not mean that things have changed fundamentally. It is just a few details that got changed to raise security and prevent easy miss usage. I am certain you will take this step. :-)

Comment: `// result not displaying` What result should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the code to display results returned from `db_select` function. `db_select` function returns database result set in an array. You need to traverse through the array and display values in HTML.

```
<?php

echo "<P>Table 1: Members:</P>";
// result not displaying
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM members WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");

if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}
else
{
    foreach($rows as $v)
    {
          //Display html code
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to thank Samir for his or her answer to my question. I have found it to be very helpful to my needs.

I wish to share my modified code, now that it works, for other people who may come across this question and find the answer beneficial to their needs.

### outputed.php

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>title</TITLE>
<STYLE>
TEXT-DECORATION=NONE
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<STYLE>
A {TEXT-DECORATION: NONE}
</STYLE>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#D9FFD9" TEXT="Black" LINK="Black" ALINK="Black" VLINK="Black">

<CENTER>

<!---------------- HEADER ------------------->

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0">

<TR><TD COLSPAN="3">&nbsp;</TR>

<TR>
<TD WIDTH="340" ALIGN="left"><A HREF="url.html" TARGET="_blank"><IMG SRC="image.jpg" WIDTH="62" HEIGHT="62" ALT="Help"></A>
<TD WIDTH="350" ALIGN="center"><IMG SRC="image.jpg" WIDTH="143" HEIGHT="62" ALT="text">
<TD WIDTH="350" ALIGN="right"><B>Powered by: wAmp 2.5</B></P>Brought to you by:<BR><IMG SRC="image.jpg" ALT="text">
</TR>

</TABLE>

</P>

<HR WIDTH="1000">

</P>

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10">

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center" BGCOLOR="#338928"><B><FONT COLOR="white" SIZE="5">outputted.php</FONT></B></TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TR>

<!---------------- BODY ------------------->

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4"><FONT COLOR="black" SIZE="5">Please check that the results are correct before prodeeding:</FONT></P></TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center"><HR WIDTH="1000"></B></TR>

<TR><TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TR>

</TABLE>

</CENTER>

<!---------------- PROCCESSING DATA FROM PREVIOUS PAGE WHICH WAS A FORM ------------------->

<?php   

//First I call for the functions
require("db_functions.php");

//variables - stored data from previous page.
$member_Id=$_POST['member_Id'];
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
$Po_Box=$_POST['Po_Box'];
$Street=$_POST['Street'];
$City=$_POST['City'];
$State=$_POST['State'];
$Country=$_POST['Country'];
$Del=$_POST['Del'];
$WFTD=$_POST['WFTD'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$DateJoined=$_POST['DateJoined'];
$Type=$_POST['Type'];
$RenewalDate=$_POST['RenewalDate'];
$LastContacted=$_POST['LastContacted'];
$MYOB_ID=$_POST['MYOB_ID'];
$Comment=$_POST['Comment'];

//Insert the values into the database

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`member_id`,`title`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`po_box`,`street`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`del`,`phone`,`mobile`,`email`,`wftd`) VALUES ('','$Title','$LastName','$FirstName','$Po_Box','$Street','$City','$State','$Country','$Del','$phone','$mobile','$email','$WFTD')");

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `ship_info` (`member_id`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`date_joined`,`type`,`renewal_date`,`last_contacted`,`myob_id`) VALUES ('','$LastName','$FirstName','$DateJoined','$Type','$RenewalDate','$LastContacted','$MYOB_ID')");

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`member_id`,`lastName`,`firstName`,`comment`) VALUES ('','$LastName','$FirstName','$Comment')");

echo"Attempting to display your last entered entry:</P>";

//-----------------------------------------Displaying First Table----------------------------------------------

// select criteria
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM members WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");

if($rows === false) {
$error = db_error();
}
else
{
foreach($rows as $v)
{

echo "<P><B>Table 1: Members:</B></P>";
echo "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=10 CELLPADDING=10>";

//Display first row - titles
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Member ID</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Title</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Last Name</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>First Name</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>P.O. Box</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Street</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>City</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>State</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Country</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Delivery Method</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Phone</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Mobile</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>eMail</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Word For The Day</B>";
echo "</TR>";

//Display second row - record
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Member_Id'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Title'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['LastName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['FirstName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Po_Box'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Street'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['City'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['State'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Country'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Del'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Phone'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Mobile'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['eMail'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['WFTD'] . " ";
echo "</TR>";

echo "</TABLE>";
}
}

//-----------------------------------------Displaying Second Table----------------------------------------------

// select criteria
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM ship_info WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");

if($rows === false) {
$error = db_error();
}
else
{
foreach($rows as $v)
{

echo "<P><B>Table 2: Ship_Info:</B></P>";
echo "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=10 CELLPADDING=10>";

//Display first row - titles
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Member ID</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Last Name</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>First Name</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Date Joined</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Type</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Renewal Date</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Last Contacted</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>MYOB ID</B>";
echo "</TR>";

//Display second row - record
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Member_Id'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['LastName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['FirstName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Date_Joined'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Type'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Renewal_Date'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Last_Contacted'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['MYOB_ID'] . " ";
echo "</TR>";

echo "</TABLE>";
}
}

//-----------------------------------------Displaying Third Table----------------------------------------------

// select criteria
$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE firstname='$FirstName' AND lastname='$LastName'");

if($rows === false) {
$error = db_error();
}
else
{
foreach($rows as $v)
{

echo "<P><B>Table 3: Comments:</B></P>";
echo "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=10 CELLPADDING=10>";

//Display first row - titles
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Member ID</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>LastName</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>FirstName</B>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF><B>Comment</B>";
echo "</TR>";

//Display second row - record
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Member_Id'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['LastName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['FirstName'] . " ";
echo "<TD BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF>" . $v['Comment'] . " ";
echo "</TR>";

echo "</TABLE>";
}
}

?>

<!---------------- FOOTER - LINKS ------------------->

<CENTER>

<TABLE WIDTH="1020" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10">

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD><HR WIDTH="1000"></TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="image.jpg"><A HREF="url.html"><FONT SIZE="5">Input Next Record?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="image.jpg"><A HREF="url.html"><FONT SIZE="5">Return Home?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD><IMG SRC="image.jpg"><A HREF="url.html""><FONT SIZE="5">Contact Admin?</FONT></A></TR>

<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TR>

</TABLE>

</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have not displayed the code from the previous page which is only a html form. Since it contains lengthy pull-down selectable items, I have decided not to include it here. I hope that some of you will find this helpful.